# Extension Method irregular behavior

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Consider the following:

```
public static class FileSerializer
{
    public static void SaveToFile<T>(this T obj, String fileName)
    {
        String dbFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName);

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(dbFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            lock (obj) bFormatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        }
    }

    public static void LoadFromFile<T>(this T obj, String fileName, Boolean ensureExists)
    {
        String dbFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName);

        if (!File.Exists(dbFile))
            if (ensureExists)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not Found!");
            else return;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(dbFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (stream.Length > 0)
            {
                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                obj = (T)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I attach the debugger, and obj in the last line of the above code, has records, when I use the method as such:

```
lstServers.LoadFromFile("Servers.dat", false);
```

*lstServers* is **ALWAYS** empty.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadFromFile` should not be an extension method, just a normal static method that returns its result:

```
lstServers = FileSerializer.LoadFromFile("Servers.dat", false);
```

The problem is that you assign to the instance parameter, and that doesn't have any effect on the variable passed to that parameter outside the method. You can't have by reference (`ref` or `out`) in an instance parameter in an extension method, which is what you would need to make your code work.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially trying to change the reference of `obj` which can't be done in this way. The best you're going to get is a non-extension version of it:

```
public static T LoadFromFile<T>(String fileName, Boolean ensureExists)
{
    String dbFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName);

    if (!File.Exists(dbFile))
        if (ensureExists)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not Found!");
        else return default(T);

    using (Stream stream = File.Open(dbFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had done this in this *ugly* way:

```
public static T LoadFromFile<T>(this String fileName, Boolean ensureExists);
```

so you can call it

```
MyType myObject = filename.LoadFromFile<MyType>(true);
```

But the biggest drawback is that this extension function will now be offered for every string.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I suspect it has to do with poluting string instances with a method which is not valid on most strings. Better to just make this a vanilla static method.

Comment: @Jamiec: Yes i no that this is not a good approach, so i called it the *ugly way*. Maybe i had made this a little more clear. *sigh*

Comment: Its not ugly, its *bad practice*. Ugly would have been using single letter variables, and non-standard naming conventions.